# how to set a variable in terraform to determine a wildcard

Tags: terraform

I have a variable `${var.dp_instance}`
and sort of chop it to determine whether the wildcard should be dp-dev* or dp-test* or dp-prod*

something like this:

```
locals {
  is_dev = contains("${var.dp_instance}", "dev")
}
```

and set up a variable to tell me whether it's dev/test/prod

```
security_group_name = local.is_dev ? "dp-dev*-worker_sg" : local.is_test ? "dp-test*-worker_sg" .......
```

I'm trying all of this to plug in here:

```
variable "eks_security_group_name" {
  description = "Name of security group(s) to allow"
  default     = "dp-dev*-worker_sg" 
}
```

Update:
The SGs contains other names like
`dp-fdp1-*worker_sg` (there is no dev/tets/prod keyword here, so I dont want to consider this SG) So I want to eliminate such SGs and only consider SGs which start with either
`dp-dev*` / `dp-test*` / `dp-prod*`

I tried doing like this :

```
variable "eks_security_group_name" {
  description = "Name of security group(s) to allow"
  default     = "dp-[dev|stage|prod]*-eks_worker_sg" #only consider SGs which have dev/test/prod) 
}
```

But this doesn't work as expected.. it would still pull in all SGs other than those which contain dev/test/prod

Comment: Care to add a bit more context? I.e., why would you need that? Does the SG really contain a wildcard or you want it to match multiple SGs by using the wildcard?

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: I want to match multiple SG by using wildcard. 
Basically the SGs contains other SGs which are like dp-fdp1-uswest-eks-worker-sg
so I want to eliminate all such SGs from the list and only allow SGs with wildcard as 
dp-dev* / dp-test* / dp-prod*

Comment: Hi @MarkoE , does my explain help? Can you please help me here !

Comment: Depending on the Terraform version, you could use the `validation` option to make sure only variables with names that you want to use are assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Terraform >=0.13.0, you could use the `validation` option for the values assigned to variables [1]:

```
variable "eks_security_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the Security Group."
  default     = "dp-dev*-worker_sg"

  validation {
    condition     = length(regexall("dev|stage|prod", var.eks_security_group_name)) > 0
    error_message = "The security group name has to contain dev/stage/prod."
  }
}
```

As one of the answers mentioned, you could use `regexall` [2] built-in function. However, this function returns a list of matches and the `condition` has to be a value of type `bool` (i.e., `true` or `false`). In order to achieve this, you can use additional built-in function `length` [3]. If the list (from the `regexall` result) is longer than 0, that means there was a match. With a default value for the `eks_security_group_name` you have defined, this condition will always evaluate to `true`. However, if you set it in `terraform.tfvars` (or any other `*.tfvars` file) to something like:

```
eks_security_group_name = "something-without-required-substrings"
```

This will cause Terraform to throw an error:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 112:
│  112: variable "eks_security_group_name" {
│ 
│ The security group name has to contain dev/stage/prod.
│ 
│ This was checked by the validation rule at variables.tf:117,3-13.
╵
```

EDIT: Since Terraform 0.12 is used, the variable validation does not work. As per the comment, `contains` built-in function does not work because it operates on a list and not a string. Following a similar logic to variable validation in 0.13 and the comment, the following can be done:

```
locals {
  is_dev   = length(regexall("dev", var.dp_instance)) > 0
  is_test  = length(regexall("test", var.dp_instance)) > 0
  is_prod  = length(regexall("prod", var.dp_instance)) > 0
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#custom-validation-rules

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regexall

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/length

Comment: I added an example based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a terraform function for that https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regexall

Comment: I have seen this, but I'm new to terraform. How do we use this function and where?

Comment: Add it in your locals where you define `is_dev`, you can do something like `length(regexall(pattern, string))` that's going to return a boolean value, so you can reuse it in your code using `count`, for example: `count = is_dev ? 1 : 0`, etc...